# How to populate master detail combobox in VB?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have two **Comboboxes** with Master Detail Relationship Table **Bank** and **Branch**

[image]

My VB code behind:-

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        
        Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\New\Test.accdb")



            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Bank, ID from Bank", con)
                Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable

                da.Fill(dt)


                ComboBox1.DataSource = dt

                ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Bank"
                ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
                ComboBox1.Text = "Select"
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim bankId = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString
        Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\New\Test.accdb")
            Using branch_cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Branch from Branch where Bank_id ='" & bankId & "'", con)
                Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(branch_cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                da.Fill(dt)
                ComboBox2.DataSource = dt
                ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Bank"
                ComboBox2.ValueMember = "ID"
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to populate in second combo box based on first combobox selected value, but the code got error on
ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged function:

[image]

And, from debugging the branch_cmd sql is:

```
Select Branch from Branch where Bank_id ='System.Data.DataRowView'
```

Comment: What is the datatype of _Bank_id_ on the database table Branch?

Comment: Number, I am using Access DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I was about to add a note and then I realised that this note is actually the solution to your actual problem. You are setting the `DataSource` first and then the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` afterwards. That is wrong and the reason for your issue. When you set the `DataSource` you have done the binding, so everything happens then and there. The first item in the list is selected so your `SelectedIndexChanged` handler is executed. You haven't set the `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember` yet, so the `SelectedValue` won't return the appropriate value. ALWAYS set the `DataSource` last, as I have done in my example below.

ORIGINAL:

Unless you have a large amount of data, you should just get all the data from both tables upfront, bind the data and then let the binding take care of the filtering automatically. You do that using `BindingSources` and binding the child to a `DataRelation` rather than a `DataTable`. Behold!

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim parentTable = GetParentTable()
    Dim childTable = GetChildTable()

    Dim data As New DataSet

    'Create a foreign key relation between the tables.
    data.Tables.Add(parentTable)
    data.Tables.Add(childTable)
    data.Relations.Add("ParentChild", parentTable.Columns("ParentId"), childTable.Columns("ParentId"))

    'Bind the parent BindingSource to the parent table.
    parentBindingSource.DataMember = "Parent"
    parentBindingSource.DataSource = data

    'Bind the child BindingSource to the relation.
    childBindingSource.DataMember = "ParentChild"
    childBindingSource.DataSource = parentBindingSource

    parentComboBox.DisplayMember = "ParentName"
    parentComboBox.ValueMember = "ParentId"
    parentComboBox.DataSource = parentBindingSource

    childComboBox.DisplayMember = "ChildName"
    childComboBox.ValueMember = "ChildId"
    childComboBox.DataSource = childBindingSource
End Sub

Private Function GetParentTable() As DataTable
    Dim table As New DataTable("Parent")

    table.PrimaryKey = {table.Columns.Add("ParentId", GetType(Integer))}
    table.Columns.Add("ParentName", GetType(String))

    table.Rows.Add(1, "Parent 1")
    table.Rows.Add(2, "Parent 2")
    table.Rows.Add(3, "Parent 3")

    Return table
End Function

Private Function GetChildTable() As DataTable
    Dim table As New DataTable("Child")

    table.PrimaryKey = {table.Columns.Add("ChildId", GetType(Integer))}
    table.Columns.Add("ChildName", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("ParentId", GetType(Integer))

    table.Rows.Add(1, "Child 1.1", 1)
    table.Rows.Add(2, "Child 1.2", 1)
    table.Rows.Add(3, "Child 1.3", 1)
    table.Rows.Add(4, "Child 2.1", 2)
    table.Rows.Add(5, "Child 2.2", 2)
    table.Rows.Add(6, "Child 2.3", 2)
    table.Rows.Add(7, "Child 3.1", 3)
    table.Rows.Add(8, "Child 3.2", 3)
    table.Rows.Add(9, "Child 3.3", 3)

    Return table
End Function
```

If you do that, selecting a parent will automatically filter the children displayed for selection.

In case it's not obvious, you would get the parent and child tables by querying a database rather than building them manually, as I have done in my example.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands now I can see two errors. First, do not concatenate strings to build sql command texts. Use always a parameterized query, specifying exactly what is the datatype of the parameter that you are passing. Second error is in the DisplayMember and ValueMember for the second combo. You don't have here a Bank_Id or a Bank name but the Branch name

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    ' Always check if you have a valid selection to avoid NRE.  
    if ComboBox1.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End if

    ' If bankid is an integer then convert to an integer
    Dim bankId as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\New\Test.accdb")
        Using branch_cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Branch from Branch where Bank_id =@id", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = bankId 
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(branch_cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            ComboBox2.DataSource = dt
            ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Branch"
            ComboBox2.ValueMember = "Branch"
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

According to your comment below you get a *System.Data.DataRowView* as the element contained in the *SelectedValue*. This should not happen with the code shown in your question, so perhaps, there is something different that creates the problem. (For example, if the datatable fields names don't match with the ValueMember/DisplayMember properties)

In any case, from a DataRowView, you should be able to get the integer in this way

```
Dim drv = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, DataRowView)
if drv IsNot Nothing then
   Dim bankid = Convert.ToInt32(drv("ID")) 
   ...
End if
```

Comment: in line-> Dim bankId as Integer:     Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: That's weird. In the filling for the first combo you set the ValueMember to the ID field and I assume that this id is a number as well. So the SelectedValue should be an integer not a DataRowView. It seems like the first combo has not set correctly the displaymember and valuemember, but then you shouldn't see the Bank name but just a list of _System.Data.DataRowView_

Comment: Just as in the code in the question, you are setting the binding properties in the wrong order. See my answer for details.